# 2 way sync of MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, amazon-rds, database-mirroring

A web application runs both on live and local server with live and local database server. Users use live server to add the data, whereas internal staffs use the local application to update the data. After some time, both of these databases have to be synchronized properly without loss of data from live or local database server. I don't want an exact replica of live database in local database or vice-versa but databases need to synchronize values which have been entered in it.

Comment: do you want to use both database in one application or you want to copy one database data to another? which one way want to do that??

Comment: That is a nice project. Not trivial, but 2 servers are doable. The important step is to define what you mean by "properly": e.g. describe what should happen if both sides update the same data (or if/how you forbid this) or data with an indirect effect on other data (e.g. marking a duplicate, setting default values, adding an invoice/...), the synchronization interval, what's done automatically or by a human. The more details you define, the easier it is for the developer you give this project to to check if there is already an out-of-the-box-solution for it and otherwise codes it for you.

Comment: **describe what should happen if both sides update the same data (or if/how you forbid this)**
Only latest data has to be getting updated.                                              
 **the synchronization interval, what's done automatically or by a human** Ethier way @Solarflare

Comment: **do you want to use both database in one application or you want to copy one database data to another? **
Yes, both DB to has to be synchronized (2 ways). will be used by the same application. but run on local and other runs on server @SanjayKumaar

Comment: so you have to create two dbconnection for that.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if I made it clear enough: such a synchronisation task is not trivial. And it requires you to define *exactly* how it should be done. This cannot be done in 2 sentences in a comment on stackoverflow! Write some pages (with examples), describing your data, who changes what and how it shall be synronized in all possible situations. That's actually the hard part. Then give it to a developer or do it yourself (stackoverflow doesn't write that code for you). You can post your requirements on e.g. softwarerecs.stackexchange.com to ask if there is an out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: edited so question is more clear